# Create form input with attributes assigned from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to prepend an input element to a form for each URL parameter using an object I create based on the URL parameters (since some have more than others).

First, I grab the URL parameters and create the object.

```
var urlParams = location.search.substring(1);
let parameters = JSON.parse('{"' + urlParams.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}', function(key, value) { return key===""?value:decodeURIComponent(value) });
```

Currently, from a URL: /test-form?utm_source=sig&utm_medium=email&utm_content=comm

This is the expected object:
parameters {utm_source: 'sig', utm_medium: 'email', utm_content: 'comm'}

Next, I want to create the input element. The most important attributes in the element are the name and the value field. I have tried a ton of different ways, but I keep running into syntax errors. This is the latest iteration of what I am trying. It has a syntax error. I got this from the for...in documentation on MDN.

```
for (property in parameters) {
    $('<input>', {
        type: 'text',
        id: `${property}`,
        name: `${property}`,
        value: `${parameters[property]}`
}).prependTo('form');
```

I thought that it was because of the property and property values, so I tried to store them in a variable inside of the for...in, but it creates the same issue.

What I expect is:

```
<input type="text" id="utm_source" name="utm_source" value="sig">
<input type="text" id="utm_medium" name="utm_medium" value="email">
<input type="text" id="utm_content" name="utm_content" value="comm">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the closing bracket on your for...in.

```
for (property in parameters) {
    $('<input>', {
        type: 'text',
        id: `${property}`,
        name: `${property}`,
        value: `${parameters[property]}`
     }).prependTo('form');
}
```